# Choosing between reference (T&) and const pointer (T* const)

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style, reference

Is there any *reasonable* use case, where one should use `const` pointer over reference?

```
T obj;
T &r = obj;  // style-1
T* const p = &obj; // style-2
```

Both the style can be used for the same purpose. I always prefer the 1st style in the code and consider the later style as **deprecated**. However I still wonder if missed any use case where 2nd style is better ?

**Edit**:  Not limiting to the above example, I talk in a broader sense,

```
void foo (T& r); // style-1
void foo (T* const p); // style-2
```

[I see from few of the answers that, style-2 allows to pass null.]

Comment: For what purpose?  I know this code is illustrative of the syntax you are asking about, but in what real code scenario are you wondering about?

Comment: For functions, the constness of the by-copy argument is an irrelevant implementation detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `const` pointer (`T* const`) can be `NULL`, and that can be useful when passing arguments to a function or when returning values from a function. For example, if you have a search function, you might want it to return `NULL` if it didn't find anything. You can't do that if it returns a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

Let me go out on a limb here. Since you explicitly say "const pointer", I'm assuming that you are *not* talking about function arguments or even function return values. For a function argument passed by copy, the constness is an irrelevant implementation detail:

```
void foo(T *);          // declaration

void foo(T * const pt)  // implementation,
{ /* ... */ }           // pt is const inside the body (who cares?)
```

Therefore, the only use case that comes to mind is if you need to make an alias somewhere inside your own code. In that case I'd always prefer the reference. Compare:

```
for (auto it = box.begin(); it != box.end(); ++it)
{
  T & trinket = *it;     // nice
  T * const ptr = &*it;  // wtpf?

  // ...
}
```

---

Since you edited your question: There is obviously a difference for function arguments.

```
void foo(T &);
void bar(T *);
```

In `foo` you are guaranteed to have a workable, mutable object reference; in `bar` you have to check whether the pointer is not null (giving you the notion of an *optional* argument). In that sense, `T&` and `T*` aren't really comparable.

Comment: May be you misunderstood. `T&` (not `const T&`) and `T* const` (not `T*`) are very much comparable. They are almost same, except the signature and the fact that pointer can be passed null (as suggested in few answers).

Comment: I know. But `T&` and `T*` are not. And for function calls, there is no such thing as `T * const`.

Answer (score 1):

For function arguments, I much prefer pointers to references, because I can tell at the call site that the parameter is an out parameter.  If the function argument is a const reference, then I prefer references.

The other big difference is `r` can't be null, so if you need it to be, then you need style-2

Comment: Nevermind; the mobile interface doesn't seem to support deleting comments.

Answer (score 0):

1) When using reference, the object must be stored in variable. For example, you can't do this:

```
void funct (T &);
funct (T ("Calling constructor"));
```

Must do:

```
void funct (T &);
T obj ("Calling constructor");
funct (obj);
```

2) When using reference, you cannot test it's value (eg. check if it's NULL which is commonly used)

By everything else, it's the same thing.

I generally use them only if it's important that function is called with true variable as argument. I might be old fashioned, but pointer way is better for me in every other cases.

Comment: In your case (1) it's a temporary variable and actually it's a good thing that we are not able to store it in reference.